# Cant display Plotly go graph with python file

Tags: python, plotly

I try to execute my python file with below command:

```
python3 show_graph.py
```

My show_graph.py is as below:

```
categories = ['First','Second','Fourth',
              'Fifth']

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=[38,
         44,
         25,
         11],
      theta=categories,
      fill='toself',
      name='testingonly'
))

fig.update_layout(
  polar=dict(
    radialaxis=dict(
      visible=True,
      range=[-100, 100]
    )),
  showlegend=True
)

fig.show()
```

But when I execute the python file. it just stop and shows nothing.

Updates:

I tried to use :

```
fig.show(renderer="png")
```

but still not worked.

Comment: Is it not possible or is it hard to achieved?

Comment: I ran your code in my environment. It correctly displays the graph as intended. My environment is plotly:5.11.0.

Comment: Thank you. May I know is your png generated too? Or was it just printing the words ?

Comment: I just checked the modified question, so I specified the renderer and checked the results. It is displayed in the image. My development environment is on jupyterLab 3.5.0, plotly latest version.

Comment: I see. thank you once again. I think it might be due to my container. Currently, I opened it via container. thank you.